# Twilio Programmable Video : Is it possible to have a one to one audio while in a group room?

Tags: php, video, twilio

So, let's say I'm an invigilator doing a proctoring for an exam. Firstly, I can talk to the candidates, at the same time they're able to talk to me (one to many). But then there's a candidate who wants to ask a discrete question, so they'll click the "talk privately" button. And all other candidates cannot hear both the candidate and I talking (one to one).

Is it possible to do this in a group room without having to create another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be possible using Programmable Video [Track Subscriptions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/track-subscriptions).